# Columnas Dinamicas - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, datatables, sql, pivot

Tengo dos tablas el cual quiero que mediante un Query SQL Server me pueda generar columnas dinámicas dependiendo de la cantidad de registros de una tabla. Por favor vean la imagen.

[image: Imágen de Tablas]

Comment: [Una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/) de igual forma [sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/). Sugiero que leas [ask] y tomes el [tour] para que veas cómo funciona la comunidad. Bienvenido a [es.so] ;)

Comment: Gracias de todas formas, logré encontrar la solución. Ya lo publico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución a lo que necesitaba. Les comparto. Hice uso de STUFF de SQL:

```html
 SELECT A.codEmpresa
   ,A.nomEmpresa
   ,A.codSistema
   ,A.nomSistema
   ,A.codPerfil
   ,A.nomPerfil
   ,modulos = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + M.nomModulo
         FROM smpseg.[0004] R
         JOIN smpseg.[0014] SMOP
         ON SMOP.codSistema = R.codSistema
         AND SMOP.codModulo = R.codModulo
         AND SMOP.codPerfil = A.codPerfil
         AND SMOP.objDefault = CAST(1 AS BIT)
         JOIN smpseg.[0011] O
         ON O.codSistema = SMOP.codSistema
         AND O.codModulo = SMOP.codModulo
         AND O.codObjeto = SMOP.codObjeto
         JOIN smpseg.[0010] M
         ON M.codSistema = O.codSistema
         AND M.codModulo = O.codModulo
        WHERE R.codUsuario = @p_codUsuario
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
  FROM smpseg.[0004] A
   JOIN smpseg.[0016] U
    ON U.codUsuario = A.codUsuario
```