# ¿Cómo usar el nombre de las columnas en una sola columna?

Tags: sql, sql-server

He estado tratando de convertir el nombre de los campos de una tabla en una sola columna:

*Este es el resultado de la consulta:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para transportarla de esta manera:

*Resultado a obtener:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si existiera más de una columna el resultado debería de verse de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con Pivot y con Unpivot pero no he tenido el resultado esperado. ¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: O sea que esa tabla siempre va a tener una sola fila con datos?

Comment: Puede tener más registros

Comment: y cuál sería el resultado que quieres cuando haya más de una fila de datos?

Comment: Podrias mostrar que intentaste con pivot?

Comment: esto no sera para resolver un problema de la vista no? que pasa si hay mas de un registro? como deberian venir?

Comment: Si existiera se debería de ver algo asi
-----------------------------------------
|NombreAreaContractual| Mexico1  |
---------------------------------
|Anexo                |  J1      |
---------------------------------
|PuntoMedicion     | CC Palomas1|
---------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
|NombreAreaContractual| Mexico2  |
---------------------------------
|Anexo                |  J2     |
---------------------------------
|PuntoMedicion     | CC Palomas2|
---------------------------------

Comment: por favor agrega el ejemplo con más de una fila y el resultado que quieres en la pregunta, no como comentario

Comment: Edité ya la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CONVERT(sql_variant, [Area]) as [Área Contractual],
            CONVERT(sql_variant, [Anexo]) as [Anexo],
            CONVERT(sql_variant, [Mes]) as [Mes]
        FROM
            dbo.compraVentaCrudo
    ) as t
UNPIVOT(FieldValue for FieldName in ([Área Contractual],[Anexo],[Mes])) as unpvt
```

Comment: Recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar "STUFF"

Aquí tuve la misma incógnita, esta publicación quizás te ayude. [STUFF](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114376/columnas-dinamicas-sql-server-2012)

Answer (score 0):

También puedes intentar con `CONCAT()`

```
CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] )
```

Y le pondrías un `AS`

Quedaría algo así:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(CONVERT(sql_variant, [Area]),
CONVERT(sql_variant, [Anexo]),
CONVERT(sql_variant, [Mes])) AS t 
FROM
       dbo.compraVentaCrudo
```